# HTML Coordinate Distance Calculator not printing

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, coordinates, document.write

I've been working on this HTML/Javascript code using the Haversine formula, in order to tell the distance between two devices. It's not currently finished however the code should be readable. For some reason "d" the final variable for the distance isn't printing (document.write) after calculation. The site is currently hosted at http://magebattle.netau.net/ however in order to make this post clean please view the source code on there, instead of me putting it all here. (Sorry about indentation)
Relevant JS:

```
            // Wait for device API libraries to load
            //
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            // device APIs are available
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
            }
            // onSuccess Geolocation
            //
            function onSuccess(position) {
                var lat2 = position.coords.latitude             
                            var lon2 = position.coords.longitude
                            var lat1 = 42.806911; 
            var lon1 = -71.290611; 
            var R = 6371; // km 
            //has a problem with the .toRad() method below.
            var x1 = lat2-lat1;
            var dLat = x1.toRad();  
            var x2 = lon2-lon1;
            var dLon = x2.toRad();  
            var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + 
                            Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
                            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);  
            var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
            var d = R * c; 
            document.write(d);
            }

            // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
            //
            function onError(error) {
                alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                    'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }
        Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
                    return this * Math.PI / 180;
        }
```

Comment: show some of the relevant js

Answer (score 0):

The function is fine, it can give results if you invoke. It seems the deviceready isn't trigger, did you try using your mobile device instead?

Comment: I have tried using a mobile device, however to no avail. Nothing new appears, unfortunately.

Comment: How should I go about invoking the function?

Comment: Call  onDeviceReady() under console.